# How to change minimize event behavior in PyQt or PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm developing a Qt application and changed the closing behavior with the [`closeEvent` virtual function](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html?highlight=setparent#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.closeEvent) this way:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def closeEvent(self, event):
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            self.trayicon.showMessage('Running', 'Running in the background.')
```

This works as expected. If I remove `event.ignore()` the application quits as expected, everything is fine.

I want to control the minimize event too, so when the user clicks the minimize button on the title bar, I want to move the window instead of minimize.
I cannot use the [`hideEvent`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html?highlight=setparent#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.hideEvent) virtual function, because the event will be sent to the window anyway, so this code:

```
def hideEvent(self, event):
    event.ignore()
    self.move(0,0)
```

moves the window to the top left AND then minimize it. `event.ignore()` has no effect here, so I tried using [`QtCore.QObject.event`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QObject.html?highlight=event#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QObject.event) this way:

```
def event(self, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.WindowStateChange:
        if self.isMinimized():
            event.ignore()
            self.move(0,0)
            return True
    return False
```

The window moves but minimizes again. What is wrong with this ? How can I override the minimize event completely ?

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`changeEvent`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html) and filter for [`WindowMinimized`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qevent.html#Type-enum) events, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.systemTrayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.systemTrayIcon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("face-smile"))
        self.systemTrayIcon.setVisible(True)
        self.systemTrayIcon.activated.connect(self.on_systemTrayIcon_activated)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Minimize me!")

        self.layoutVertical = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.label)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.ActivationReason)
    def on_systemTrayIcon_activated(self, reason):
        if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.DoubleClick:
            if self.isHidden():
                self.show()

            else:
                self.hide()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                event.ignore()
                self.close()
                return

        super(MyWindow, self).changeEvent(event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        self.hide()
        self.systemTrayIcon.showMessage('Running', 'Running in the background.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If I run this, the window title stays on the taskbar. When I click to that the MyWindow will be grey and empty. strange.  If I change `self.hide()` to self.move(), the minimization still happens after the move. :(

Comment: @Walkman Checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16048802/1006989), I updated it to modify the behavior on the minimize event

Comment: same effect, strange behaviour. title bar stays on windows taskbar, and when I try to `self.move(0,0)` it moves AND minimizes again. I updated my question, maybe it's more clear what I want.

Comment: @Walkman The code above works fine over here, that looks like some OS related issue, try using a `QTimer`, that would be `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.close)` instead of `self.close()`

Comment: Singleshot doesn't work either, so it might be a problem on Windows 8 then ! Thanks anyway for trying!